# Calculating the cut off frequency of a filter circuit if you know all the component values

Tags: filter

I realise this might seem like a rookie question, and there must be plenty of info out there about it, but I am so new to electronics  I don't understand the information I'm finding well enough.

Basically, I'm trying to build a 3rd order butterworth filter from a schematic. I don't have exactly the same capacitor values, so I'd like to know how to calculate the cut off frequency resulting from the components I do have. I'm certain this formula is also on the same Web page, but again I'm so inexperienced, I'm struggling to figure out which of the many formulas it might be.

This is the circuit diagram:

[image]

And this is the website it comes from:

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_8.html

Any help here would be much appreciated, and explanations as to how to recognise the right formula and why would also be awesome! I like to work towards self sufficiency whenever possible.

Pete

Comment: see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/74884/143764)

Comment: @andre That's a good link. The circuit is an equal component value Sallen-Key with a damping factor of 1, which means some very slight overshoot (\$\sqrt{2}\$ would be critical damping) and a gain of 2 at the opamp output and before the final RC filter. Too bad the link you gave doesn't *directly* discuss the damping (or damping ratio.)

Comment: With different values, the cutoff of the first of the two cascaded stages is \$f_c=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{R_a R_b C_a C_b}}\$ and the damping is \$\frac{1}{Q}=d=\frac{\sqrt{R_a C_b}}{\sqrt{R_b C_a}}+\frac{\sqrt{R_b C_b}}{\sqrt{R_a C_a}}-\frac{\sqrt{R_a C_a}}{\sqrt{R_b C_b}}\$. \$R_a\$ is your R facing \$V_{in}\$ and \$R_b\$ faces the (+) input of your opamp. \$C_a\$ is the feedback cap and \$C_b\$ is the grounded cap. The values for \$R_f\$ and for \$R_1\$ have their ratios right but their magnitudes in the circuit are set way too low and I don't see how the author got their magnitudes.

Comment: Also, there is another rule. 1st order filters should generally *precede* the 2nd order chain and the filters in the 2nd order chain should flow from highest damped to lowest damped, going from input towards output, in order to prevent largish out-of-band signals from either ringing or clipping at the output. However, the author may have wanted the 1st order RC at the end to avoid the need of a follower opamp or else to keep the input impedance higher.

Comment: @jonk, Hello jonk, your comment is interesting regarding the cascading of filters with different damping ratios. It is true that transfer function-wise, the different cascaded configurations do not change the Bode plot.  Do you have links or documents supporting this argument? Thank you.

Comment: @VerbalKint Cascaded damping values come from factoring by filter choice. Been 40+ years, but the ordering made immediate sense (gain peaking vs f), so I retained it. Not sure of the source, now, but try L Weinberg's "Network Analysis and Synthesis" or G E Tobey's "Operational Amplifiers -- Design and Applications" or D Lancaster's "Active Filter Cookbook." My abrupt forced reading came from a 6-pole transmit/10-pole receive filter in an FSK modem. I'm a hobbyist with not even so much as one hour of electronics training, bolstered only by a joy for math. Keep my limitations in mind. +1 to you.

Comment: @jonk, merci ! This is kind of you, I will look up the sources you gave. Your receiver filter for a FSK modem was surely fun to derive its transfer function : )

Comment: @VerbalKint I've enjoyed your contribution here. (I downloaded both PDFs and have spent time reading through them.) In a way, though, your single-minded focus on it reminds me of a man with a chainsaw, to whom everything looks now like a tree. ;) (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument .) But it is a pretty good chainsaw and what you have presented is gradually adding to my skill set and I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @jonk, I did not know this interesting law and I am certainly not a lumberjack even if I am an outdoor guy : ) I hope my modest contributions to this nice site will encourage students and engineers to further dig the FACTs and apply them widely: when you've tried them, you do not want to go back to the classical approach!

Comment: @VerbalKint Yes, at least I have personally enjoyed and benefited from the perspectives offered. By no stretch was it completely novel. But that is a good thing for me as I was able to follow along more quickly because of that. It offered some new "resonances" that I appreciated gathering up. Glad to have spent some time on it and I'll let it deepen inside, over time and use. Thanks.

Comment: @VerbalKint I have found the reference about damping order, which I believe may be the first published case (though I'm not sure.) It is on page 16 of "Technical Report No. 50", 6 May 1954, "A Practical Method of Designing RC Active Filters," by Sallen and Key. This report is from MIT Lincoln Laboratory and predates their IEEE paper by a year, I think. It's 31 pages long and you have to ask MIT to ask the USAF to get permission to read their "Unclassified" document! (But I just asked, had to provide my reasons why, and after a time finally received an authorized copy!) It is under "control."

Comment: @VerbalKint Also see http://www.pci-card.com/mfb_lp.pdf , page 3, left side under "Circuit Implementation" and also http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/phase-relations-in-active-filters.html , in paragraph near bottom just above Figure 18.

Comment: @jonk, Hi, thanks a lot for these links, they are very useful. I now understand the reason low-\$Q\$ sections must precede higher \$Q\$ circuits: output saturation of some of the stages can occur because of gain peaking if that order in not preserved. Merci for kindly shedding some extra light on these particular arrangements that I was not aware of.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thanks for asking me why I said something, too! I think it is important that we insist on "why" something is said and I'm glad you did. Each of us should double-check their memory before writing. There is too much garbage in the world, already. In this case I did research what I wrote *before* I wrote it, checking some of my notes. But I should only say things where I can, if asked, go back and answer questions like yours. In this case, I enjoyed tracing my notes to the original reference. Sadly, it is a military controlled doc. So I made a formal request to get a copy and got it.

Answer (score 6):

This is an active Sallen-Key filter followed by a passive low-pass filter. The transfer function of the whole circuit is that of a 2nd-order polynomial form followed by a 1st-order \$RC\$ filter: this is a 3rd-order filter. If we consider the op amp a perfect element, its output impedance is 0 and thus eliminates the interaction with the \$RC\$ filter. We can thus first determine the transfer function of the S&K filter, simply followed by the transfer function of the low-pass filter to obtain the whole expression linking \$V_{out}\$ to \$V_{in}\$. Let's start with the active filter.

There are plenty of options to determine the transfer function of this active filter. The fastest and most efficient to me are the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs described [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371). It consists of determining the time constants \$\tau\$ of the circuit when the excitation \$V_{in}\$ is reduced to 0 V. But first, we determine the dc gain of the circuit shown below with the adopted component labels:

[image]

To determine the dc gain for \$s=0\$, open the capacitors and determine the circuit gain \$H_0\$ in this configuration. You see an op amp wired in a non-inverting configuration whose gain is: \$H_0=\frac{R_f}{R_i}+1\$. The bias point simulation shows 2 V for a 1-V input confirming a gain of 2 with equal values for \$R_f\$ and \$R_i\$.

Now, reduce the excitation to 0 V (replace \$V_{in}\$ by a short circuit) and determine the resistance "seen" from the capacitor terminals when it is temporarily removed. The resistance multiplied by the capacitor forms the time constants we want. The below drawing will help you determine these:

[image]

To determine a resistance, inspection works in the upper left sketch. As \$C_2\$ is removed, you see the current generator biasing the two resistors \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ in series. So without writing a line of algebra, the first time constant is immediate: \$\tau_1=C_1(R_1+R_2)\$. For the second time constant, a few lines are necessary to determine the resistance. The second time constant is \$\tau_2=C_2R_1(1-A_v)\$ with \$A_v=\frac{R_f}{R_i}+1\$. The final time constant is obtained when \$C_2\$ is replaced by a short circuit and you determine the time constant involving \$C_1\$: \$\tau_{21}=C_1\frac{R_2}{1-A_v}\$. We can now assemble \$D(s)\$ by combining the time constants as follows: \$D(s)=1+s(\tau_1+\tau_2)+s^2\tau_2\tau_{21}\$. This can be advantageously rearranged under a canonical form \$D(s)=1+\frac{s}{Q\omega_0}+\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{0}}\right)^2\$ in which \$Q=\frac{\sqrt{b_2}}{b_1}\$ and \$\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b_2}}\$. When you combine all these elements together, you have \$Q=\frac{\sqrt{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}{(R_1+R_2)C_1+R_1C_2(1-A_v)}\$ and the resonant frequency \$\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}\$. With the given component values, you have \$f_0=45.2\;Hz\$ and \$Q=1\$. All these expressions are computed in the below Mathcad sheet:

[image]

We have the denominator but do we know if there are zeros in this circuit? To check the presence of a zero, short the capacitor and check if a response still exists in this mode. If yes, there is a zero associated with the capacitor you have shorted, if not, there is no zero contributed by this element. Shorting any of the caps or both at the same time gives 0 V as confirmed by the below sketch: there is no zero and \$N(s)=1\$.

[image]

The final transfer function for the S&K section is thus:

\$H(s)=H_0\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{Q\omega_0}+\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{0}}\right)^2}\$. We can plot this transfer function as shown below:

[image]

We can check our calculation integrity with a SPICE simulation or by using the following [site](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPstool.php):

[image]

The resonant frequency and quality factor are identical to what I found and the frequency response is the same:

[image]

Ok, we now have the active filter part and the final result includes the passive low-pass section whose transfer function is simply:

\$H_{LP}(s)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$ with \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{R_LC_L}\$. The final transfer function of this 3rd-order filter is given by:

\$H_{3rd}(s)=H_0\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{Q\omega_0}+\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{0}}\right)^2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$.

We can plot this expression and see the new downslope of 60 dB per decade confirming the 3rd-order behavior:

[image]

FACTs are well suited because you just calculate time constants via individual sketches you can later correct if necessary. You can also simulate these small schematics (as I did) in case you want to check you results. Proceeding step by step is the key to determining the transfer function in a swift and efficient manner. Highly recommended for designers dealing with transfer functions!

Comment: This is a truely incredible answer! Thanks a lot. I have been reading through it this morning, and I think I'm starting to understand, but I'm going to be working on this circuit again tonight when I get home, so I'm certain I'll have some further questions regarding this later ;)

Comment: @Iron Attorney, thank you, I am glad if my answer helped you understand this circuit. If you want to take a look at what the FACTs have to offer, please have a look at this seminar taught at the 2016 APEC conference, it should be a smooth introduction to the technique: http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you! I will come back to that, I am currently going through more similes filter circuits to properly learn the maths and understand the concepts. I am still also going through the information given in the answers and comments here, so hopefully in the next few days I should be up to speed here. Then I'll have to figure out which of the two great answers I should mark as correct, lol

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking us how to derive such formulas, and that's a great question!

The truth is: you simply have to analyze the circuit like the network of components it is, and derive voltages and currents from the network, and put formulas into formulas, until you get a formula for output voltage Vout that depends on input voltage Vin.

## Right part of the circuit

Because looking at the whole circuit is a bit daunting (and also, unnecessary!), let's look at the right part (the one right of the dashed line) alone:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCCHbV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm deliberately leaving out the component values – we'll find the formula for Vout(Vin), and you can put in the values yourself. I'll put a few terms into *italics*; if you haven't heard them before, you **should** read up on them. They form the very basic of electronics.

Now, look at R5--C3. It's basically a voltage divider – the same current \$I\$ must flow through R5 and C3 (we model Vout as just being an "open" output), that's *Kirchhoff's first law* and thus, we know that the voltage \$U\$ over R5 must be \$U_{R_5}=I\cdot R_5\$.

Furthermore, we know that the voltage over C3 is Vout, and that this voltage plus the voltage over R5 must be Vin – *Kirchhoff's second law* (Kirchhoff's Voltage Law). So:

$$\begin{align}
V_{in} &= V_{out}+U_{R_5}\\
\implies
V_{out} &= V_{in} - U_{R_5}\\
&= V_{in} - I\cdot R_5 \tag1
\end{align}$$

But what is \$I\$? Ok, we also know that

$$\begin{align}
V_{in} &= I \cdot (R_5+Z_{C_3})\\
&\text{$Z_{C_3}$ being the $\textit{complex impedance}$ of the capacitor,}\\
&\text{ and we know what that is, $Z_{C_3}=\frac1{j\omega C_3}$:}\\
&= I\cdot \left(R_5+\frac1{j\omega C_3}\right)\\
\implies\\
I &= \frac{V_{in}}{R_5+\frac1{j\omega C_3}}\tag2
\end{align}$$

So thanks to complex numbers, we can act as if our capacitor was just like a resistor with a specific, frequency-dependent complex value. That frequency-dependency is expressed in \$\omega = 2\pi f\$.

Let's move on and insert \$(2)\$ in \$(1)\$:

$$\begin{align}
V_{out} &= V_{in}-I\cdot R_5\\
&= V_{in}-R_5 \frac{V_{in}}{R_5+\frac1{j\omega C_3}}\\
&= V_{in} \left(1-\frac{R_5}{R_5+\frac1{j\omega C_3}}\right)\tag4
\end{align}$$

So, \$(4)\$ gives us the output voltage of this *RC-filter* as a complex voltage. We often only care about the amplitude of that voltage, not the phase shift (i.e. the magnitude of the complex voltage, not its angle), so we often calculate and plot the \$\left\lvert V_{out}\right\rvert\$ for a whole series of circular frequencies \$\omega\$. Together with a plot of the angle of the complex voltage, we call that a *Bode plot*.

## Left part of the circuit

This part is a bit more tricky. But really, you just apply *Kirchhoff's laws* and the *golden rules of the operational amplifier* to get another output/input voltage relationship, and plot that.

To be honest, it's getting late and I don't know how much you'd really profit from a pages-long derivation of the math behind an active filter – so, I'd say, start with practicing to calculate simple LC, RC, CR, LR, RLC filters, and if you got these down, get yourself comfortable with an applied book on active filters – I think TI and Analog devices both have nice books on those on their website, but they absolutely require you're used to complex currents, passive filters and Bode plots.

Comment: Yep, that is what I'm asking :D I have been going through the answers and comments tonight, trying to get a real grasp of this, and I am getting somewhere. Thank you for your detailed answer :D I'm still not quite there yet though, so I'll probably still be back some time with flow up questions. I have scaled back my circuit to simple RC, RL and inverting op amp circuits to help me properly understand the concepts and the maths. It's definitely making more sense now

Comment: Actually, here's something I'm confused about. In the right side of the circuit, there is Vin from the left on both terminals of the non-polarized capacitor, and both flow straight to Vout on the right hand side. So, does anything actually happen across the capacitor? Does R5 cause increased flow across the capacitor in a particular direction? This is I guess assuming that. Vin is the same for both the top and bottom parts of the circuit..

Comment: Voltage doesn't flow - current does. And the current has to pass through the resistor, over which it results in a voltage drop, depending on how much current flows. At higher frequencies, more current flows through the capacitor, hence through the resistor, hence for high frequency, there is more voltage drop over r5, and hence less voltage Vout.

Comment: The two Vin points, and the two Vout points... Do they each represent a single connection? Or are these a positive and ground connection of an input signal, and a positive a ground connection of an output? I was assuming the former, but now I think about it, the latter would probably make more sense

Comment: Otherwise everything would be directly connected to ground... Haha. That wouldn't work! Sorry, I think I've just fixed my understanding of the right hand side of the circuit :D