# (Audio) Line Level RC - 24db LPF

Tags: filter, passive-filter

Ive been messing with RC Low Pass Filters for a few days now but ive ran into a Problem: I cant seem to increase my slope. Right now im at 3db/oct (I think?). With a single pole RC filter. Ive tried stacking them but that doenst seem to do anything.

My source is an audio signal thats being amplified by a NPN transistor (with a DC offset so the ATmega can process it). Then I have my RC filter which seems to work fine but i need more attenuation.

From 150Hz on I want a 24db slope, what do I need to change? 
Audio quality is not a concern as its just being processed by a micro for beat detection.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon the huge output capacitance of your filter is not ideal. If 16.8 dB attenuation per decade still fulfills your requirements, you could use the following circuit:

You were also burning a lot of current through your BJT. I have increased the collector's resistance and the base bias resistor.
If you still need a higher gain, say 40dB decade, you can use a second order low pass like the Sallen-Key filter described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74877/gain-in-sallen-key-filter).

[image: Circuit]

[image: WAveform]

Comment: Play with the filter tool here: https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/amplifier-and-linear-tools.html

Comment: Changing the impedances as proposed may be a problem depending on the impedances of the source and load.

Comment: Since you have 1 transistor to play with, use it in emitter follower (unity gain) configuration and implement a Sallen & Key filter around that. That'll give you a 12dB/octave filter. As you want 24 dB/octave, you'll need a second transistor. Then you can build a 4th order Sallen & Key filter (I recommend a Butterworth filter characteristic) as 2 second order stages. Couple of useful search terms in there.

Comment: okay ive recreated this circuit and it already works alot better than what i had, thanks! The BJT also stays cool now. But now my DC offset voltage is at 0.7 but i need it centered at 2.5V (Micro reads 0-5V) - can i just change the first voltage divider to do this?

Comment: Also, I added a second 100nF in Parallel to get 80Hz, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, increasing the base resistance will reduce the base current, thus the collector voltage will increase. I ran a quick simulation, and a 510kOhm resistor would bring the collector voltage up to around 2.5V. Adding this additional capacitor in parallel does exactly what you said. I hope you aware that his circuit is not very stable because of the BJT's gain.