# Can you explain this active filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, filter, signal-processing, frequency-response

I am trying to analyze the open source project OpenEEG's schematics. I came across a filter which  supposedly has a 59 Hz cut-off frequency. I could not locate the 59 Hz pole of the filter. Can you please explain it to me?

This is an EEG device and the filter's purpose is to eliminate the mains voltage noise. The first two poles and the last pole of the filter, which is located at an other module of the system, is given below.

First two poles:
[image: First two poles]

Last pole at the digital part with many channels:
[image: Last pole]

Comment: I bet we can, but can you be more specific what kind of explanation about it you want? What do you want to know about it?

Comment: What is a besselworth filter?

Comment: @Justme, how does it operate, why does it says cut-off frequency is 59 Hz when I can not detect any RC network with 59 Hz cut-off frequency?

Comment: @Andyaka I have no idea :(

Comment: Apparently the coined (hence the scare quotes) word "Besselworth" refers to a kind of [blend](https://openeeg.sourceforge.net/doc/modeeg/modeeg_design.html) of Bessel and Butterworth filter characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the question is. Are you looking for a mathematical explanation, or will a simulation suffice?

The active filter is a Sallen-Key low-pass filter topology. If you do a SPICE simulation, you'll see that the gain is about 24 dB (16x), low-frequency cutoff formed by C1 and the input impedance of the active filter is about 0.190 Hz, the high-frequency cutoff due to the active filter and the R-C filter at the output is about 59 Hz.

The equations for the Sallen-Key low-pass filter can be found in this StackExchange [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74877/gain-in-sallen-key-filter).

Simulation using LTspice. Note, the opamp is the LTspice universalopamp which is an analog behavioral model (ABM) of an opamp which is why it doesn't need power.
[image]

Comment: I believe the RC (7.5K and 220n) forms a filter with fc around 100Hz. Can you explain that please? Thanks.

Comment: \$ 1/{(2 \pi RC)} \$ gives a corner frequency of 96.5 Hz. This adds a 3rd pole which makes the roll-off steeper at higher frequencies. It may also provide a suitable input decoupling for the input of an A/D converter judging by the net names.

Comment: so if the third pole adds a corner at 96.5 Hz, how does the cut-off frequency of the filter is 59Hz?

Comment: Short answer, the active filter has a corner frequency around 67 Hz if the opamp has a gain bandwidth product of 1.7 MHz. When you multiply the response of the active filter with the RC filter, you will end up with a corner frequency around 59 Hz. As an educational exercise, I would suggest modeling this filter in SPICE and take a look at the response at various places in the filter chain such as at node a, b, and out.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration of circuit is known as Sallen-Key filter. In your case it has an additional gain path as well (the 100k & 8.2k).

Knowing this you should be able to work out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Without the C-R highpass at the input, the shown circuit is a specific derivat of the known Sallen-Key topology. Classical 2nd-order S&K lowpass stages have either (a) equal componenets for R and C within the filter network or (b) typical fixed gain gain values (0dB or 6dB).

The shown circuit has a pretty large gain of app. 22.5 dB and an additional capacitor
which causes a continuous gain reduction (down to 0 dB) above a frequency of app. 2 kHz.

To me, the purpose of this capacitor is not quite clear. In the question, a source for the name ("Besselworth") is mentioned. In this source, they say that this special filter would have better constant delay properties (if compared with a Butterworth response). However, according to my simulations I cannot confirm such a statement.