# Problems with output signal of a 2nd order low pass Sallen Key filter for an electret microphone

Tags: filter, microphone, low-pass, electret, sallen-key

I'm having problems with a small circuit based on the amplification of a audio signal received by an electret microphone. It goes to a 2nd order Sallen Key low pass filter circuit with an amplification of nearly 26 dB. The schematic has the commercial values of the components I'm using on my protoboard. Vcc and Vee are two  9V batteries. The op amp that I'm using is the TL074.

[image]

The output of my signal from this circuit through my oscilloscope is a square wave. I don't know what is happening here. Is a signal that I didn't expect to receive.

[image]

Comment: Have you computed the damping factor?

Comment: Check that you haven't got pins 2 & 3 swapped over on the op amp.

Answer (score 3):

> *The output of my signal from this circuit through my oscilloscope is
> an square wave. I don't know what is happening here.*

Sallen key filters cannot be used when the gain required is this high because they turn the circuit into an oscillator. The maximum gain for a Sallen key filter is 3 (same value input resistors and same value capacitors) according to [this website](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/sallen-key-filter.html#:%7E:text=Sallen%2Dkey%20Filter%20Response,Q%20would%20lead%20to%20oscillations.): -

[image]

The only option is to reduce the Q factor, use two op-amps stages or, implement an [MFB filter](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa114/sboa114.pdf?ts=1696495886323&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

See also my answer from [Gain in Sallen-Key filter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/74884/20218) and note this: -

[image]

Comment: Yup. That was the point of my question above. Gain and damping factor are not independent in this Sallen Key. I was just taking my time getting to the point, asking a question insead. +1